# angular ngFor list item not showing

Tags: angular, ngfor

I want to display a simple `ul` element with some `li` in it. For this I created this component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'skin',
  templateUrl: './skin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./skin.component.css']
})
export class SkinComponent {

  skins: [{
    id: 1,
    className: 'color-circle blue light',
    skinName: 'Blue light'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    className: 'color-circle orange light',
    skinName: 'Orange light'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    className: 'color-circle lime light',
    skinName: 'Lime light'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    className: 'color-circle purple light',
    skinName: 'Purple light'
    },
  {
    id: 5,
    className: 'color-circle teal light',
    skinName: 'Teal light'
  }
  ];

  constructor() { }

}
```

And this is the corresponding html:

```
  <ul class="schemes" style="float: left">
    <li *ngFor="let skin of skins">
      <span class="{{skin.className}}"></span>
      <span class="color-name">{{skin.skinName}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

But if I compile the app, there is no list item. The `ul` element gets rendered of couse, but without `li` items.

In the browser I see this:

[image]

What is here the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have set your list value as `type` instead of assigning them as `value` inside your variable.

**From this:**

```
skins: [{ ... }]
```

**Change it to this**

```
skins = [
  {
    id: 1,
    className: 'color-circle blue light',
    skinName: 'Blue light'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    className: 'color-circle orange light',
    skinName: 'Orange light'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    className: 'color-circle lime light',
    skinName: 'Lime light'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    className: 'color-circle purple light',
    skinName: 'Purple light'
    },
  {
    id: 5,
    className: 'color-circle teal light',
    skinName: 'Teal light'
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `:` to `=` for any array you have to declare type annoation !

**Changes**

```
skins = [{ARRAY'S OBJECT}]
```

**.ts file**

```
    skins =  [{
      id: 1,
      className: 'color-circle blue light',
      skinName: 'Blue light'
      }, {
     id: 2,
      className: 'color-circle orange light',
      skinName: 'Orange light'
    }
   ];
```

let me know if it's not working !
Hope it will usefull for !